# Definition of map genericity in topology

Tags: differential-topology, definition

In many articles about topology, Reeb space etc. I came accross the term `generic map`, or `generic smooth map` but I haven't found any definition of such "genericity"... could you help me ?

Example of use from https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/36ea/f7d4db2653769b39ff7927c38e812f3eba87.pdf :

> We study the local and global structure of this space for generic, piecewise linear mappings on a combinatorial manifold.

Comment: I believe generic is being used literally here, in place of "any". It indicates generality.

Comment: It ordinarily signifies a dense (often open, too) set of mappings in an appropriate topology on the space of mappings.

Comment: @The Count I'm not sure : in http://www.ee.oulu.fi/research/imag/courses/Vaccarino/Edels_Book.pdf , Edelsbruner dedicate a part aoubt "generic maps" where he says that smooth mappings enough to "tame" mappings on manifold, while "generics mapping" does... However, I haven't seen any formal definition of his "genericity"

Comment: In the case of this specific example, the definition is given right in the article you linked, in the second paragraph of the "background" section: "[w]e call
$f$ a *generic PL mapping* if the images of the vertices have no structural properties that can be removed by arbitrarily small perturbations of the vertex map."